# Is this correct regarding velocity of train?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

[image]

So many yellow T drawn are just different position of train at different instants.The person  is standing still at all those instants at one place.

If a train is moving at 5m/s.

Then for me , can we say that the speed of train will be magnitude of blue line . I just drew it rough for now just to at-least check am I right or wrong.

Then , velocity of train with respect to man keeps on changing as angle between the blue line with changes which means magnitude of blue line changes.

Answer (score 0):

if the train is at a constant velocity relative to the ground and the observer stands still (does not move relative to the ground) then the train is is moving at a constant velocity relative to the observer as well.
You may ask how the angle of one point on the train changes with respect to time. This property won't be constant and will be biggest as the point is nearest to you and smaller as it's further.

Comment: The relative velocity between you and the object does not change because the train still gets further away from you in a constant rate - 5 meters each second.

Comment: Why is that ? The direction at which the observer looks at train is sometimes north east , then north and then north west.So , velocity doesn’t look to be Constant for P.

Comment: Of course the position of the train changes and by that the corresponding angle change. However, the direction of the train's motion is the same and the distance between P and the train changes at a constant rate.

Comment: Only the direction and magnitude determines the velocity (as it is a vector). The fact that both are the same implies that the velocity is constant.

Answer (score -1):

Just to expand on @Neta Drori's answer, I think some of the confusion here is due to the difference between what P would measure and what P would see. A measurement is based on the assumption that P's frame of reference has "rulers" and "clocks" distributed throughout and these would indeed determine that the velocity of the train is constant.

P sees something different. He sees the direction of the train changing, implying a change in velocity. This change, for a given time interval, is greatest when the train is the middle position in OP's diagram and gradually decreases as the train moves further away. At some distant point, the change in the train's direction would be imperceptible.

But it always has a constant velocity in P's frame of reference.

Comment: You said in your second paragraph that velocity changes? But in last you say it doesn’t ?

Comment: P sees what APPEARS to be a change in velocity due to his viewpoint. You are asking about a subjective velocity based on what P sees. If P were very far away then in any short time interval the train would not APPEAR to move at all and have zero velocity. That's okay to ask about but it is not what is commonly meant by the velocity with respect to P. Relative velocity of train with respect to P is v(train) - v(P), both measured with respect to a frame of reference. In this case, v(P)=0 so relative velocity with respect to P is v(train).